# QTextBrowser won't append link correctly if that link has equals sign inside it

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt, qt4

```
class TextBrowser(QtGui.QTextBrowser):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QTextBrowser.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAcceptRichText(True)
        self.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
        self.insertHtml('<a href=' + 'https://www.google.com/#q=dfsdf'+'>' + 'gg' + '</a>')
        self.append('<a href=' + 'https://www.google.com/#q=dfsdf' + '>' + 'gg' + '</a>')
```

So anytime I try to append link that has equals sign QTextBrowser will append only part of the link before the sign. https://www.google.com/#q=dfsdf will become https://www.google.com/#q

```
setHtml()
```

works correctly but I just want to add clickable link - not to clean the whole area to display link only.
Anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always make sure html attributes are enclosed in double-quotes, otherwise special characters like `=` may be parsed wrongly. The html should look like this:

```
    <a href="https://www.google.com/#q=dfsdf">gg</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would never guess that's the case )